# The Wall - mootools - Slideshow stops working after drag

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm having a problem with the slideshow animation of my Wall. It works upon load but it stops working after I drag it. I can click on the images and it'll still work, but stops when I drag the whole wall. Any ideas on what might be causing this? I've been trying to solve this for a while but can't get it to work. Is it something with my movement? Here's my code below:

```
var counter   = 0;
var mediaWall = new Wall("myWall", {
    "draggable":true,
    "autoposition":true,
    "inertia":true,
    "width":275,
    "height":275,
    "slideshow":true,
    "transition":Fx.Transitions.Expo.easeInOut,
    "showDuration": 6000,
    callOnUpdate: function(items) {
        items.each(function (e, i) {
            var tw = mentions[counter];
            createAndInjectNode(mediaWall, counter, tw, e);
            counter++;
            if (counter >= mentions.length)
                counter = 0;
        });
    }
});
mediaWall.initWall();
```

Comment: The Wall is a very old Mootools plugin. Since its latest release, Mootools have been updated a lot. What version of Mootools are you using? If you don't know, open your browser's console and type `MooTools.version`.

Comment: @lorenzo-s MooTools.version is 1.6.0. It's the latest

Comment: On the plugin page the requirement is Mootools 1.3.2, which is very old. Try download 1.6.0 with **compat layer** from **[here](http://mootools.net/core/builder)**. If it not works, **choose a previous version** using the dropdown **[here](http://mootools.net/core)** and use the 1.3.2 instead of the new 1.6.0 version. If it works you have two options: stick with the older version (if you can), or tweak the source of the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem by adding the following in `CallOnUpdate`:

```
if (mediaWall.getMovement()) {
  mediaWall.clearSlideShow();
  mediaWall.initSlideshow();
```